# QtAV in QT in QML

Tags: qt

i am using QtAV but getting this error so please help me:
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:4 plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtAV": Cannot load library /home/intel/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/qml/QtAV/libQmlAV.so: (libswresample.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

at qrc:/main.qml:4 import QtAV1.6
using linux

Answer (score 0):

The application cannot find your requested plugin.

You need to check if your import path is set correctly. If this is the case: please check if the plugin is installed correctly. You can use

```
export QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1
```

to check which import pathes are set.

And make sure, that all dependncies are installed as well. For instance libswresample ( see https://ffmpeg.org/libswresample.html )

Comment: all dependencies have been installed properly but only error occur in qml in cpp its perfect

Comment: Are all paths set correctly ( LD_LIBRARY_PATH for instance ) with the correct version ( same compiler etc. ).

Comment: i have installed QtAV 1.11.0